# How can I get data out of the same model in different ways for parsing to Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, model

Using C# .Net5

I am trying to find out if there is a way of having a model something like this:

```
public class CollectionOptionModel
{
    public string sport { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public int fromDay { get; set; }
    public int fromMonth { get; set; }
    public int fromYear { get; set; }
    public int toDay { get; set; }
    public int toMonth { get; set; }
    public int toYear { get; set; }
    public int? eventId { get; set; }
    public string eventName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TypeModel> marketTypesCollection { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TypeModel> countriesCollection { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<TypeModel> fileTypeCollection { get; set; }
}
```

The issue is I also need the same data in a different format to send to an API as I only want the collections to return an array of values when serialized by newton soft like so:

```
    public class CollectionOptionDownloadModel
{
    public string sport { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public int fromDay { get; set; }
    public int fromMonth { get; set; }
    public int fromYear { get; set; }
    public int toDay { get; set; }
    public int toMonth { get; set; }
    public int toYear { get; set; }
    public int? eventId { get; set; }
    public string eventName { get; set; }
    public List<string> marketTypesCollection { get; set; }
    public List<string> countriesCollection { get; set; }
    public List<string> fileTypeCollection { get; set; }
}
```

and return data needs to be associated with each variation passed into the API via a list of filenames like so:

```
public class SingleOptionResultsModel
{

    public string sport { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public int fromDay { get; set; }
    public int fromMonth { get; set; }
    public int fromYear { get; set; }
    public int toDay { get; set; }
    public int toMonth { get; set; }
    public int toYear { get; set; }
    public int? eventId { get; set; }
    public string eventName { get; set; }
    public string marketTypesCollection { get; set; }
    public string countriesCollection { get; set; }
    public string fileTypeCollection { get; set; }
    public List<string> fileList { get; set; }
}
```

This works as it is, but I have to do a few for-loops to copy the data across to each model.
Is there a way of using custom getters and setters to achieve this in a better way? Since I am new to coding I know I miss a few tricks, and since there looks like there will be a lot of instances where this would be useful, I thought I would ask for some advice.

Comment: \*cough\* automapper. Or any other mapper

Comment: Too many questions, try to paraphrase and make your question shorter. It is hard to understand what is about.